# Heatmap DC.js - how to filter multiple items manually

Tags: javascript, heatmap, dc.js

I'm working on a heatmap chart using dc.js. During the page loads, i want to manually filter the heatmap.

For example, if it filter using this heatmap.filter("30,0"); it works when the page loads. but when i try to filter multiple values using the .filter() function, it didnt work.

I tried doing this just for testing.

```
    var test = [];

    test.push("30,0");
    test.push("40,2");
    heatmapChart.filter(test);
```

Though it works if its only one item, but if i add another array item, the chart breaks. Is there a specific way to filter multiple items manually?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but there are a few layers of weird between here and there.

First, the actual filter items are constructed using [dc.filters.TwoDimensionalFilter](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.filters.TwoDimensionalFilter.html) - I think your comma separated strings are only working by accident.

Second, the chart has already overridden `.filter()` so if you want to get at the base version which can handle multiple items, you need to call `chart._filter()` instead.

Finally, and weirdest of all, the syntax for filtering on multiple items is to supply an array containing a single array of filter items.

Putting these all together,

```
    var ff = [dc.filters.TwoDimensionalFilter([0,2008]),
              dc.filters.TwoDimensionalFilter([3,1994]),
              dc.filters.TwoDimensionalFilter([9,2000])];
    heatmapChart._filter([ff]);
```

works with the [heatmap filtering example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/heatmap-filtering.html). Note the array of array of filters!