# keeping the selection in sync between two heatmaps

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

[image]

I am building multiple Heat-maps from a sample data set given below.

```
[
  {
    "x2": 1,
    "y2": 1,
    "x2_TT": 20,
    "y2_TT": 23
  },
  {
    "x2": 1,
    "y2": 1,
    "x2_TT": 20,
    "y2_TT": 23
  },
  {
    "x2": 1,
    "y2": 1,
    "x2_TT": 20,
    "y2_TT": 23
  },
  {
    "x2": 1,
    "y2": 1,
    "x2_TT": 20,
    "y2_TT": 23
  },
  {
    "x2": 1,
    "y2": 1,
    "x2_TT": 20,
    "y2_TT": 23
  },
  {
    "x2": 1,
    "y2": 1,
    "x2_TT": 20,
    "y2_TT": 23
  },
  {
    "x2": 1,
    "y2": 1,
    "x2_TT": 20,
    "y2_TT": 23
  },
  {
    "x2": 1,
    "y2": 1,
    "x2_TT": 20,
    "y2_TT": 23
  },
  {
    "x2": 1,
    "y2": 1,
    "x2_TT": 20,
    "y2_TT": 23
  },
  {
    "x2": 1,
    "y2": 1,
    "x2_TT": 20,
    "y2_TT": 23
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.9163309159,
    "y2": 0.9163309159,
    "x2_TT": 18,
    "y2_TT": 21
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.9163309159,
    "y2": 0.9163309159,
    "x2_TT": 18,
    "y2_TT": 21
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.9163309159,
    "y2": 0.9163309159,
    "x2_TT": 18,
    "y2_TT": 21
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.9163309159,
    "y2": 0.9163309159,
    "x2_TT": 18,
    "y2_TT": 21
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.9163309159,
    "y2": 0.9163309159,
    "x2_TT": 18,
    "y2_TT": 21
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.9163309159,
    "y2": 0.9163309159,
    "x2_TT": 18,
    "y2_TT": 21
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.9163309159,
    "y2": 0.9163309159,
    "x2_TT": 18,
    "y2_TT": 21
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.9163309159,
    "y2": 0.9163309159,
    "x2_TT": 18,
    "y2_TT": 21
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.9163309159,
    "y2": 0.9163309159,
    "x2_TT": 18,
    "y2_TT": 21
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.9163309159,
    "y2": 0.9163309159,
    "x2_TT": 18,
    "y2_TT": 21
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.7849029059,
    "y2": 0.7849029059,
    "x2_TT": 16,
    "y2_TT": 19
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.7849029059,
    "y2": 0.7849029059,
    "x2_TT": 16,
    "y2_TT": 19
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.7849029059,
    "y2": 0.7849029059,
    "x2_TT": 16,
    "y2_TT": 19
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.7849029059,
    "y2": 0.7849029059,
    "x2_TT": 16,
    "y2_TT": 19
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.7849029059,
    "y2": 0.7849029059,
    "x2_TT": 16,
    "y2_TT": 19
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.7849029059,
    "y2": 0.7849029059,
    "x2_TT": 16,
    "y2_TT": 19
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.7849029059,
    "y2": 0.7849029059,
    "x2_TT": 16,
    "y2_TT": 19
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.7849029059,
    "y2": 0.7849029059,
    "x2_TT": 16,
    "y2_TT": 19
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.7849029059,
    "y2": 0.7849029059,
    "x2_TT": 16,
    "y2_TT": 19
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.7849029059,
    "y2": 0.7849029059,
    "x2_TT": 16,
    "y2_TT": 19
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.6695846541,
    "y2": 0.6695846541,
    "x2_TT": 14,
    "y2_TT": 17
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.6695846541,
    "y2": 0.6695846541,
    "x2_TT": 14,
    "y2_TT": 17
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.6695846541,
    "y2": 0.6695846541,
    "x2_TT": 14,
    "y2_TT": 17
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.6695846541,
    "y2": 0.6695846541,
    "x2_TT": 14,
    "y2_TT": 17
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.6695846541,
    "y2": 0.6695846541,
    "x2_TT": 14,
    "y2_TT": 17
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.6695846541,
    "y2": 0.6695846541,
    "x2_TT": 14,
    "y2_TT": 17
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.6695846541,
    "y2": 0.6695846541,
    "x2_TT": 14,
    "y2_TT": 17
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.6695846541,
    "y2": 0.6695846541,
    "x2_TT": 14,
    "y2_TT": 17
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.6695846541,
    "y2": 0.6695846541,
    "x2_TT": 14,
    "y2_TT": 17
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.6695846541,
    "y2": 0.6695846541,
    "x2_TT": 14,
    "y2_TT": 17
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.5604744826,
    "y2": 0.5604744826,
    "x2_TT": 12,
    "y2_TT": 15
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.5604744826,
    "y2": 0.5604744826,
    "x2_TT": 12,
    "y2_TT": 15
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.5604744826,
    "y2": 0.5604744826,
    "x2_TT": 12,
    "y2_TT": 15
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.5604744826,
    "y2": 0.5604744826,
    "x2_TT": 12,
    "y2_TT": 15
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.5604744826,
    "y2": 0.5604744826,
    "x2_TT": 12,
    "y2_TT": 15
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.5604744826,
    "y2": 0.5604744826,
    "x2_TT": 12,
    "y2_TT": 15
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.5604744826,
    "y2": 0.5604744826,
    "x2_TT": 12,
    "y2_TT": 15
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.5604744826,
    "y2": 0.5604744826,
    "x2_TT": 12,
    "y2_TT": 15
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.5604744826,
    "y2": 0.5604744826,
    "x2_TT": 12,
    "y2_TT": 15
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.5604744826,
    "y2": 0.5604744826,
    "x2_TT": 12,
    "y2_TT": 15
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.433624775,
    "y2": 0.433624775,
    "x2_TT": 9,
    "y2_TT": 12
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.433624775,
    "y2": 0.433624775,
    "x2_TT": 9,
    "y2_TT": 12
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.433624775,
    "y2": 0.433624775,
    "x2_TT": 9,
    "y2_TT": 12
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.433624775,
    "y2": 0.433624775,
    "x2_TT": 9,
    "y2_TT": 12
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.433624775,
    "y2": 0.433624775,
    "x2_TT": 9,
    "y2_TT": 12
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.433624775,
    "y2": 0.433624775,
    "x2_TT": 9,
    "y2_TT": 12
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.433624775,
    "y2": 0.433624775,
    "x2_TT": 9,
    "y2_TT": 12
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.433624775,
    "y2": 0.433624775,
    "x2_TT": 9,
    "y2_TT": 12
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.433624775,
    "y2": 0.433624775,
    "x2_TT": 9,
    "y2_TT": 12
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.433624775,
    "y2": 0.433624775,
    "x2_TT": 9,
    "y2_TT": 12
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.3117981232,
    "y2": 0.3117981232,
    "x2_TT": 7,
    "y2_TT": 10
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.3117981232,
    "y2": 0.3117981232,
    "x2_TT": 7,
    "y2_TT": 10
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.3117981232,
    "y2": 0.3117981232,
    "x2_TT": 7,
    "y2_TT": 10
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.3117981232,
    "y2": 0.3117981232,
    "x2_TT": 7,
    "y2_TT": 10
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.3117981232,
    "y2": 0.3117981232,
    "x2_TT": 7,
    "y2_TT": 10
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.3117981232,
    "y2": 0.3117981232,
    "x2_TT": 7,
    "y2_TT": 10
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.3117981232,
    "y2": 0.3117981232,
    "x2_TT": 7,
    "y2_TT": 10
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.3117981232,
    "y2": 0.3117981232,
    "x2_TT": 7,
    "y2_TT": 10
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.3117981232,
    "y2": 0.3117981232,
    "x2_TT": 7,
    "y2_TT": 10
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.3117981232,
    "y2": 0.3117981232,
    "x2_TT": 7,
    "y2_TT": 10
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.2070667799,
    "y2": 0.2070667799,
    "x2_TT": 5,
    "y2_TT": 8
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.2070667799,
    "y2": 0.2070667799,
    "x2_TT": 5,
    "y2_TT": 8
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.2070667799,
    "y2": 0.2070667799,
    "x2_TT": 5,
    "y2_TT": 8
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.2070667799,
    "y2": 0.2070667799,
    "x2_TT": 5,
    "y2_TT": 8
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.2070667799,
    "y2": 0.2070667799,
    "x2_TT": 5,
    "y2_TT": 8
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.2070667799,
    "y2": 0.2070667799,
    "x2_TT": 5,
    "y2_TT": 8
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.2070667799,
    "y2": 0.2070667799,
    "x2_TT": 5,
    "y2_TT": 8
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.2070667799,
    "y2": 0.2070667799,
    "x2_TT": 5,
    "y2_TT": 8
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.2070667799,
    "y2": 0.2070667799,
    "x2_TT": 5,
    "y2_TT": 8
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.2070667799,
    "y2": 0.2070667799,
    "x2_TT": 5,
    "y2_TT": 8
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.0826720825,
    "y2": 0.0826720825,
    "x2_TT": 3,
    "y2_TT": 6
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.0826720825,
    "y2": 0.0826720825,
    "x2_TT": 3,
    "y2_TT": 6
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.0826720825,
    "y2": 0.0826720825,
    "x2_TT": 3,
    "y2_TT": 6
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.0826720825,
    "y2": 0.0826720825,
    "x2_TT": 3,
    "y2_TT": 6
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.0826720825,
    "y2": 0.0826720825,
    "x2_TT": 3,
    "y2_TT": 6
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.0826720825,
    "y2": 0.0826720825,
    "x2_TT": 3,
    "y2_TT": 6
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.0826720825,
    "y2": 0.0826720825,
    "x2_TT": 3,
    "y2_TT": 6
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.0826720825,
    "y2": 0.0826720825,
    "x2_TT": 3,
    "y2_TT": 6
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.0826720825,
    "y2": 0.0826720825,
    "x2_TT": 3,
    "y2_TT": 6
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.0826720825,
    "y2": 0.0826720825,
    "x2_TT": 3,
    "y2_TT": 6
  },
  {
    "x2": 0,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2_TT": 2,
    "y2_TT": 5
  },
  {
    "x2": 0,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2_TT": 2,
    "y2_TT": 5
  },
  {
    "x2": 0,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2_TT": 2,
    "y2_TT": 5
  },
  {
    "x2": 0,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2_TT": 2,
    "y2_TT": 5
  },
  {
    "x2": 0,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2_TT": 2,
    "y2_TT": 5
  },
  {
    "x2": 0,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2_TT": 2,
    "y2_TT": 5
  },
  {
    "x2": 0,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2_TT": 2,
    "y2_TT": 5
  },
  {
    "x2": 0,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2_TT": 2,
    "y2_TT": 5
  },
  {
    "x2": 0,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2_TT": 2,
    "y2_TT": 5
  },
  {
    "x2": 0,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2_TT": 2,
    "y2_TT": 5
  }];
```

When I select a cell from a heat-map, other than the selected cell all the other cells are defaulted to the #ccc color. In the corresponding filtered heat-maps, the color is defaulted to a primary blue color. I am attaching a image below for reference.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/3.1.5/dc.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-promise/4.1.1/es6-promise.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/3.0.0/fetch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.12.0/d3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/3.1.5/dc.js"></script>
```

```
var runDim;

var data = [
  {
    "x2": 1,
    "y2": 1,
    "x2_TT": 20,
    "y2_TT": 23
  },
  {
    "x2": 1,
    "y2": 1,
    "x2_TT": 20,
    "y2_TT": 23
  },
  {
    "x2": 1,
    "y2": 1,
    "x2_TT": 20,
    "y2_TT": 23
  },
  {
    "x2": 1,
    "y2": 1,
    "x2_TT": 20,
    "y2_TT": 23
  },
  {
    "x2": 1,
    "y2": 1,
    "x2_TT": 20,
    "y2_TT": 23
  },
  {
    "x2": 1,
    "y2": 1,
    "x2_TT": 20,
    "y2_TT": 23
  },
  {
    "x2": 1,
    "y2": 1,
    "x2_TT": 20,
    "y2_TT": 23
  },
  {
    "x2": 1,
    "y2": 1,
    "x2_TT": 20,
    "y2_TT": 23
  },
  {
    "x2": 1,
    "y2": 1,
    "x2_TT": 20,
    "y2_TT": 23
  },
  {
    "x2": 1,
    "y2": 1,
    "x2_TT": 20,
    "y2_TT": 23
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.9163309159,
    "y2": 0.9163309159,
    "x2_TT": 18,
    "y2_TT": 21
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.9163309159,
    "y2": 0.9163309159,
    "x2_TT": 18,
    "y2_TT": 21
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.9163309159,
    "y2": 0.9163309159,
    "x2_TT": 18,
    "y2_TT": 21
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.9163309159,
    "y2": 0.9163309159,
    "x2_TT": 18,
    "y2_TT": 21
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.9163309159,
    "y2": 0.9163309159,
    "x2_TT": 18,
    "y2_TT": 21
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.9163309159,
    "y2": 0.9163309159,
    "x2_TT": 18,
    "y2_TT": 21
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.9163309159,
    "y2": 0.9163309159,
    "x2_TT": 18,
    "y2_TT": 21
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.9163309159,
    "y2": 0.9163309159,
    "x2_TT": 18,
    "y2_TT": 21
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.9163309159,
    "y2": 0.9163309159,
    "x2_TT": 18,
    "y2_TT": 21
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.9163309159,
    "y2": 0.9163309159,
    "x2_TT": 18,
    "y2_TT": 21
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.7849029059,
    "y2": 0.7849029059,
    "x2_TT": 16,
    "y2_TT": 19
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.7849029059,
    "y2": 0.7849029059,
    "x2_TT": 16,
    "y2_TT": 19
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.7849029059,
    "y2": 0.7849029059,
    "x2_TT": 16,
    "y2_TT": 19
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.7849029059,
    "y2": 0.7849029059,
    "x2_TT": 16,
    "y2_TT": 19
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.7849029059,
    "y2": 0.7849029059,
    "x2_TT": 16,
    "y2_TT": 19
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.7849029059,
    "y2": 0.7849029059,
    "x2_TT": 16,
    "y2_TT": 19
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.7849029059,
    "y2": 0.7849029059,
    "x2_TT": 16,
    "y2_TT": 19
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.7849029059,
    "y2": 0.7849029059,
    "x2_TT": 16,
    "y2_TT": 19
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.7849029059,
    "y2": 0.7849029059,
    "x2_TT": 16,
    "y2_TT": 19
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.7849029059,
    "y2": 0.7849029059,
    "x2_TT": 16,
    "y2_TT": 19
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.6695846541,
    "y2": 0.6695846541,
    "x2_TT": 14,
    "y2_TT": 17
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.6695846541,
    "y2": 0.6695846541,
    "x2_TT": 14,
    "y2_TT": 17
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.6695846541,
    "y2": 0.6695846541,
    "x2_TT": 14,
    "y2_TT": 17
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.6695846541,
    "y2": 0.6695846541,
    "x2_TT": 14,
    "y2_TT": 17
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.6695846541,
    "y2": 0.6695846541,
    "x2_TT": 14,
    "y2_TT": 17
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.6695846541,
    "y2": 0.6695846541,
    "x2_TT": 14,
    "y2_TT": 17
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.6695846541,
    "y2": 0.6695846541,
    "x2_TT": 14,
    "y2_TT": 17
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.6695846541,
    "y2": 0.6695846541,
    "x2_TT": 14,
    "y2_TT": 17
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.6695846541,
    "y2": 0.6695846541,
    "x2_TT": 14,
    "y2_TT": 17
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.6695846541,
    "y2": 0.6695846541,
    "x2_TT": 14,
    "y2_TT": 17
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.5604744826,
    "y2": 0.5604744826,
    "x2_TT": 12,
    "y2_TT": 15
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.5604744826,
    "y2": 0.5604744826,
    "x2_TT": 12,
    "y2_TT": 15
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.5604744826,
    "y2": 0.5604744826,
    "x2_TT": 12,
    "y2_TT": 15
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.5604744826,
    "y2": 0.5604744826,
    "x2_TT": 12,
    "y2_TT": 15
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.5604744826,
    "y2": 0.5604744826,
    "x2_TT": 12,
    "y2_TT": 15
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.5604744826,
    "y2": 0.5604744826,
    "x2_TT": 12,
    "y2_TT": 15
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.5604744826,
    "y2": 0.5604744826,
    "x2_TT": 12,
    "y2_TT": 15
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.5604744826,
    "y2": 0.5604744826,
    "x2_TT": 12,
    "y2_TT": 15
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.5604744826,
    "y2": 0.5604744826,
    "x2_TT": 12,
    "y2_TT": 15
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.5604744826,
    "y2": 0.5604744826,
    "x2_TT": 12,
    "y2_TT": 15
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.433624775,
    "y2": 0.433624775,
    "x2_TT": 9,
    "y2_TT": 12
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.433624775,
    "y2": 0.433624775,
    "x2_TT": 9,
    "y2_TT": 12
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.433624775,
    "y2": 0.433624775,
    "x2_TT": 9,
    "y2_TT": 12
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.433624775,
    "y2": 0.433624775,
    "x2_TT": 9,
    "y2_TT": 12
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.433624775,
    "y2": 0.433624775,
    "x2_TT": 9,
    "y2_TT": 12
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.433624775,
    "y2": 0.433624775,
    "x2_TT": 9,
    "y2_TT": 12
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.433624775,
    "y2": 0.433624775,
    "x2_TT": 9,
    "y2_TT": 12
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.433624775,
    "y2": 0.433624775,
    "x2_TT": 9,
    "y2_TT": 12
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.433624775,
    "y2": 0.433624775,
    "x2_TT": 9,
    "y2_TT": 12
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.433624775,
    "y2": 0.433624775,
    "x2_TT": 9,
    "y2_TT": 12
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.3117981232,
    "y2": 0.3117981232,
    "x2_TT": 7,
    "y2_TT": 10
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.3117981232,
    "y2": 0.3117981232,
    "x2_TT": 7,
    "y2_TT": 10
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.3117981232,
    "y2": 0.3117981232,
    "x2_TT": 7,
    "y2_TT": 10
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.3117981232,
    "y2": 0.3117981232,
    "x2_TT": 7,
    "y2_TT": 10
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.3117981232,
    "y2": 0.3117981232,
    "x2_TT": 7,
    "y2_TT": 10
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.3117981232,
    "y2": 0.3117981232,
    "x2_TT": 7,
    "y2_TT": 10
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.3117981232,
    "y2": 0.3117981232,
    "x2_TT": 7,
    "y2_TT": 10
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.3117981232,
    "y2": 0.3117981232,
    "x2_TT": 7,
    "y2_TT": 10
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.3117981232,
    "y2": 0.3117981232,
    "x2_TT": 7,
    "y2_TT": 10
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.3117981232,
    "y2": 0.3117981232,
    "x2_TT": 7,
    "y2_TT": 10
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.2070667799,
    "y2": 0.2070667799,
    "x2_TT": 5,
    "y2_TT": 8
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.2070667799,
    "y2": 0.2070667799,
    "x2_TT": 5,
    "y2_TT": 8
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.2070667799,
    "y2": 0.2070667799,
    "x2_TT": 5,
    "y2_TT": 8
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.2070667799,
    "y2": 0.2070667799,
    "x2_TT": 5,
    "y2_TT": 8
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.2070667799,
    "y2": 0.2070667799,
    "x2_TT": 5,
    "y2_TT": 8
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.2070667799,
    "y2": 0.2070667799,
    "x2_TT": 5,
    "y2_TT": 8
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.2070667799,
    "y2": 0.2070667799,
    "x2_TT": 5,
    "y2_TT": 8
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.2070667799,
    "y2": 0.2070667799,
    "x2_TT": 5,
    "y2_TT": 8
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.2070667799,
    "y2": 0.2070667799,
    "x2_TT": 5,
    "y2_TT": 8
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.2070667799,
    "y2": 0.2070667799,
    "x2_TT": 5,
    "y2_TT": 8
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.0826720825,
    "y2": 0.0826720825,
    "x2_TT": 3,
    "y2_TT": 6
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.0826720825,
    "y2": 0.0826720825,
    "x2_TT": 3,
    "y2_TT": 6
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.0826720825,
    "y2": 0.0826720825,
    "x2_TT": 3,
    "y2_TT": 6
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.0826720825,
    "y2": 0.0826720825,
    "x2_TT": 3,
    "y2_TT": 6
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.0826720825,
    "y2": 0.0826720825,
    "x2_TT": 3,
    "y2_TT": 6
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.0826720825,
    "y2": 0.0826720825,
    "x2_TT": 3,
    "y2_TT": 6
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.0826720825,
    "y2": 0.0826720825,
    "x2_TT": 3,
    "y2_TT": 6
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.0826720825,
    "y2": 0.0826720825,
    "x2_TT": 3,
    "y2_TT": 6
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.0826720825,
    "y2": 0.0826720825,
    "x2_TT": 3,
    "y2_TT": 6
  },
  {
    "x2": 0.0826720825,
    "y2": 0.0826720825,
    "x2_TT": 3,
    "y2_TT": 6
  },
  {
    "x2": 0,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2_TT": 2,
    "y2_TT": 5
  },
  {
    "x2": 0,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2_TT": 2,
    "y2_TT": 5
  },
  {
    "x2": 0,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2_TT": 2,
    "y2_TT": 5
  },
  {
    "x2": 0,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2_TT": 2,
    "y2_TT": 5
  },
  {
    "x2": 0,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2_TT": 2,
    "y2_TT": 5
  },
  {
    "x2": 0,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2_TT": 2,
    "y2_TT": 5
  },
  {
    "x2": 0,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2_TT": 2,
    "y2_TT": 5
  },
  {
    "x2": 0,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2_TT": 2,
    "y2_TT": 5
  },
  {
    "x2": 0,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2_TT": 2,
    "y2_TT": 5
  },
  {
    "x2": 0,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2_TT": 2,
    "y2_TT": 5
  }];

var data1 = [];

var f=0; var c=1;
for( var i=0; i<=data.length-1; i++){
  f++;
  if(f>Math.sqrt(data.length)){ f=1; c++; }
    data[i].column = f;
    data[i].row = c;
} 

  data.filter( (x) => {
    var obj = {}
    obj.value = x.x2;
    obj.tooltip = x.x2_TT;
    obj.row = x.row;
    obj.column = x.column;
    data1.push(obj)
  })
console.log( JSON.stringify(data1) )
console.log(data);

  var ndx    = crossfilter(data);

  Object.keys(data[0]).filter(x => !x.includes('_TT') && !x.includes('column') && !x.includes('row') ).forEach(function(i, index){

  //Dynamic DIV appended to body
  var testid = "<div class='col-lg-6 dcjs' id='chart"+index+"' onclick='HeatMap(this)'></div>";
                $('#test').append(testid);

  //$("#chart"+index).append("<h4 align='center'>"+i+"</h4>")              

  var chart = dc.heatMap("#chart"+index);

  var holder = Object.keys(data[0]).filter(x => !x.includes('_TT') && !x.includes('column') && !x.includes('row'))[index];

  var width = document.getElementById('chart'+index).offsetWidth;
  var height = document.getElementById('chart'+index).offsetHeight;

      runDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return [ +d.row, +d.column, +d[holder+'_TT'] ]; }),
      runGroup = runDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return +d[holder]; });
  chart
    .width(width)
    .height(height)
    .dimension(runDim)
    .group(runGroup)
    .keyAccessor(function(d) { return [ +d.key[0],  ] ; })
    .valueAccessor(function(d) { return +d.key[1]; })
    .colorAccessor(function(d) { return +d.value; })
    .title(function(d) {
        //return "Value: " + d.key[0] + ","+ d.key[1] + " : " + d.key[2]; 
        return "Value : "+ d.key[2];
      })
    // .addFilterHandler(function (filters, filter) {
    //     filters.push(filter);
    //     console.log(filters)
    //     return filters;
    // })
    // .boxOnClick(function (d) {
    //   console.log(d.key)
    //     var filter = d.key;
    //     dc.events.trigger(function () {
    //         chart.filter(filter);
    //         chart.redrawGroup();
    //     });
    // })
    .on('pretransition', function(chart) {
        chart.selectAll('g.axis text').attr("fill", "white").style("font-size", "0px")
      }) 
    .colors(['#000080', '#000092', '#0000a4', '#0000b7', '#0000c9', '#0000db', '#0000ee', '#0000ff', '#0002ff', '#0012ff', '#0022ff', '#0033ff', '#0043ff', '#0053ff', '#0063ff', '#0073ff', '#0084ff', '#0094ff', '#00a4ff', '#00b4ff', '#00c4ff', '#00d4ff', '#00e5f7', '#0cf5ea', '#19ffdd', '#27ffd0', '#34ffc3', '#41ffb6', '#4effa9', '#5bff9c', '#68ff8f', '#75ff82', '#82ff75', '#8fff68', '#9cff5b', '#a9ff4e', '#b6ff41', '#c3ff34', '#d0ff27', '#ddff19', '#eaff0c', '#f7f500', '#ffe600', '#ffd700', '#ffc800', '#ffb900', '#ffaa00', '#ff9b00', '#ff8c00', '#ff7d00', '#ff6e00', '#ff5f00', '#ff5000', '#ff4100', '#ff3200', '#ff2300', '#ff1400', '#ee0500', '#db0000', '#c90000', '#b70000', '#a40000', '#920000', '#800000'])
    .xBorderRadius(0)
    .yBorderRadius(0)
    .calculateColorDomain();

    if (index == Object.keys(data[0]).filter(x => !x.includes('_TT') && !x.includes('column') && !x.includes('row') ).length-1 ){ dc.renderAll(); 
    }
  });

function HeatMap(event){

console.log(runDim.top(Infinity));

  // setTimeout( () => { 
  //   $('.dcjs').each(function(index, obj) {
  //     if (obj != event){
  //       $(obj).find('.box-group').each(function(indexStep, objStep) {
  //         if ($(objStep).find('rect').attr('fill') == "rgb(0, 0, 128)" ){
  //             $(objStep).addClass("deselected");
  //         }
  //       })
  //     }
  //   }); 
  // }, 500);

}
// d3.csv("morley.csv").then(function(experiments) {

// });
```

How do I override the crossfiltered applied dark blue color for other heatmaps to the same #CCC unselected color?

Here is a fiddle for the following problem: https://jsfiddle.net/Vivek_Raju/ndeuzxmt/

Comment: Find the CSS rule currently responsible for giving it the blue color. Write an new CSS rule containing the color you want. Make sure it has a higher priority than the original rule.

Comment: that is a hacky solution @Shilly. According to docs, you can update colors with the colorMixins. http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.colorMixin.html

Comment: @vivek share a jsfiddle so that it is easier for people to try out the solutions. You could try it out yourselves from the above doc

Comment: @DhananjaiPai It's a hacky solution indeed. Sometimes I wrongly assume that the people using a library have already searched their docs for out-of-the-box solutions to their problem. ;)

Comment: [This example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/heatmap-filtering.html) doesn't use exactly the same color for filtering within the heatmap vs filtering in another chart, but I think it gives the right idea - if using a `scaleLinear` just makes sure zero maps to the color you want.

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Vivek_Raju/ndeuzxmt/) Here is a fiddle for the following problem @Gordon

Comment: @DhananjaiPai I realize that the color associated with the lowest value will turn out to be the background filtered color for the rest of the Heatmaps, but i do not want to use the #ccc. So this color is not mapped to any value. How would i go about introducing in the colorMixins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion in the comments, we realized that the problem wasn't really about colors but about keeping the selection in sync between two heatmaps.

First off, if you've got two dc.js charts on the same data, you almost always want them on the same dimension. This is because you don't want them filtering each other, and [a group does not observe its own dimension's filters](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#a-group-does-not-observe-its-dimensions-filters).

So let's move the dimension out of the loop and use it for both charts:

```
const keys = Object.keys(data[0]).filter(x => !x.includes('_TT') && !x.includes('column') && !x.includes('row'));

const runDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
  return [+d.row, +d.column]; //, +d[holder + '_TT']];
});
keys.forEach(function(i, index) {
```

(I also put keys in a variable because it was hurting my brain to see that huge expression everywhere. I also moved `dc.redrawAll()` out of the loop.)

The way to set filters in dc.js is pretty idiosyncratic. Here is a question specifically about the format needed to change a heatmap filter programmatically:

[Heatmap DC.js - how to filter multiple items manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49077900/heatmap-dc-js-how-to-filter-multiple-items-manually)

Copying filters from one chart to the others can be done like this:

```
var guard = false;
function filter_listener(i) {
  return function(chart) {
    if(guard) return; // avoid infinite recursion
    var filters = chart.filters().map(f => dc.filters.TwoDimensionalFilter([f[0],f[1]]));
    console.log(i, filters);
    guard = true;
    charts.forEach((chart2, j) => {
      if(j == i) return;
      chart2._filter(null);
      if(filters.length) chart2._filter([filters])
    });
    guard = false;
  }
}

charts.forEach((chart, i) => chart.on('filtered.sync', filter_listener(i)))
```

Basically the filter listener will first make sure it is not the source of the current filters, to avoid infinite recursion.

Then it will copy the filters, and loop over all the charts.

If the current chart is not itself, it will reset the filter, and if the list of filters is not empty, it will then set the filters on the other chart.

Note the use of `._filter()`, because as noted in the cited question, the heatmap has a weird override of `.filter()` which would stop us from setting multiple filters at once. Also note the array of arrays of filters. Wow.

[Here is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/wszhpyur/69/).

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments above, you need to specify a color for the value zero that will match the deselected color.

You are already using the color mixin; it defines the `.colors()` method.

Currently you have

```
 .colors(['#000080', '#000092', // ...
```

`#000080` is your dark blue color, so change it to `#ccc` or whatever you want:

```
 .colors(['#ccc', '#000092', // ...
```

Under the default style rules, a deselected item will also have opacity 0.5, so it won't look the same color. You can restore opacity 1 in your own CSS, and also change the deselected color if you want something besides the default `#ccc`:

```
.dc-chart .box-group.deselected rect.heat-box {
  fill-opacity: 1;
  /* fill: #ccc; */
}
```

[Fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/9ksh83e1/6/).

Comment: Hi @Gordon, I do not want to add the #ccc to the colors domain, cause it will alter the color mapping for the dataset and eventually defeat it's purpose. Now let us say in the forked fiddle, I selected a rect heat-box with color #ccc. In this scenario the boxes with the #ccc color will essentially be invisible even though the crossfilter will pick the value to display it.
Can i not add the #ccc in the colors pallette and still be able to do what your forked fiddle does?
Thanks.

Comment: Furthermore if few boxes in the first heatmap are selected and we carry on the select a box in the second heatmap, all the colors which are previously selected are defaulted to the dark blue color (in my case [fiddle]) or #ccc (in your case [fiddle]). 
How do i fix this issue? 
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you have two charts displaying the same data for some reason, and you want to keep the selection in sync between them. Also you only want one box selected at a time. Is this a better description on the problem?

Comment: I am sorry if i was not very clear about my problem. Yes, you are correct and I am using the same data set to display or draw multiple Heat-maps. I would like to be able to select multiple boxes and keep it in sync with the other heat-maps keeping in mind that the color #ccc should reflect in the other charts without providing it in the colors palette. Additionally if i could implement a box selector in a heat-map which enables me to select multiple boxes at once and show the corresponding boxes highlight in the other heat-maps would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, if you sync the selection that will take care of keeping the colors the same. I can work up an answer later today. It sounds like you *do* want the multiple selection that the heatmap comes with by default, but it has terrible side effects when the selections are not synced.